# Why I can’t open a file in gVim via WEBDAV?

Tags: vim, webdav

I use WEBDAV protocol in Thunar―with that I am able to see my database as a tree of directories/files. I am able to open any file in the DB with any common editor in Linux (Gedit, Geany and so on) but not with gVim. It opens the file (takes more seconds than in other editors) but it is empty. Why?

Comment: Wild guess: disable the swap file with `set noswapfile`

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Try opening with vim -u NONE -U NONE -R

Comment: When I do this on desktop, gVim opens without its configuration (plain like fresh install). I have no idea how to open files from Thunar (via WEBDAV) there. It is not possible to drag&drop.

Comment: Ok. This probably is related with the fact that all the other editors you tried support gvfs. Try installing the daemon described here https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2008-September/msg01476.html and accessing the files ine

Comment: ... under ~/.gvfs